# NullPointerException when trying to access an agent from Main in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to send a message to an agent in a specific state from Main. I have already done this many times, but this time AnyLogic is returning the NullPointerException error.

Here is the code I am using to send the message:

```java
User chosen_user = randomWhere(users, t -> t.inState(User.Inactive));
users.get(chosen_user.getIndex()).receive("message");
```

Using `traceln(chosen_users.getIndex())` for printing the index, everything works fine. Just when I plug the index in the function get() it returns the error.

Even if I plug just a random number, let's say `users.get(1).receive("message")`, it still returns the same error (my population has 700 agents).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will just be because *no* user is in the `Inactive` state at some particular time so your `randomWhere` call returns `null`.

You also don't need the indirection of using the index; just send the message directly to it using the `send` function:

```
if (chosen_users != null) {
   send("message", chosen_users);
}
```

(Your naming is misleading too since `chosen_users` is always one `User` agent (or `null`).)

Comment: Thank you so much! I edited the question to update the variable name. I also tested your solution, but now it is returning "Index -1 out of bounds for length 700". I used traceln() to print the index and check from where this -1 was coming, but the traceln returns an index inside the bounds of my population. Anyway, I guess I will just keep trying. But I really appreciate it!

Comment: You'd get that index -1 error if you're trying to access an agent that is no longer in the population. Are you sure nothing is removing the agent from the population before you send it the message? (Also, that error suggests you are still using `getIndex` rather than just sending directly to the selected agent.)

Comment: I fixed the previous error, now the solution works. Thanks!